# Match everything before a specific word in a multiline string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to filter out some garbage text from a string with regex but can't seem to get it to work. I'm not a regex expert (not even close) and I've searched for similar examples but none that seems to solve my problem.

I need a regex that matches everything from the start of a string to a specific word in that string but not the word itself.

here's an example:

```
<p>This is the string I want to process with as you can see also contains HTML tags like <i>this</i> and <strong>this</strong></p>
<p>I want to remove everything in the string BEFORE the word "giraffe" (but not "giraffe" itself and keep everything after it.</p>
```

So, how do I match everything in the string before the word "giraffe"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"\A             # Start of string
    (?:              # Match...
     (?!""giraffe"") #  (unless we're at the start of the string ""giraffe"")
    .                #  any character (including newlines)
    )*               # zero or more times", 
    "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

should work.

Answer (score 4):

Why regex?

```
String s = "blagiraffe";
s = s.SubString(s.IndexOf("giraffe"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var s =
         @"<p>This is the string I want to process with as you can see also contains HTML tags like <i>this</i> and <strong>this</strong></p>
         <p>I want to remove everything in the string BEFORE the word ""giraffe"" (but not ""giraffe"" itself and keep everything after it.</p>";
    var ex = new Regex("giraffe.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Match(s).Value);
```

This code snippet produces the following output:

```
giraffe" (but not "giraffe" itself and keep everything after it.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) would do the trick:

```
^.*(?=\s+giraffe)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could used a pattern with a lookahead like this

`^.*?(?=giraffe)`